# Find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})*n^p, p\in N$

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I got into some trouble with this limit which leads to an indetermination in the final part:
$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})*n^p, p\in N$

The limit in the parenthesis results $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ after amplification with $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ which it's limit is $0$, but here comes the indetermination because $n$ to any power except $0$ is $+\infty$.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n \to\infty$, so you have a valid indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write : 
$$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\times n^p=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})n^p=\frac{n^p}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n^p}{\sqrt{n}\Big(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1\Big)}$$
this goes to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I don't really understand how $\frac{n^p}{2\sqrt(n)}$ goes to ∞, can you explain please? Or it just goes to ∞ and that's all?

Comment: $n^p/(2\sqrt{n})=n^p/(2n^{1/2})=n^{p-1/2}/2$ by the law of integer power.

Comment: Thanks! But the limit=∞ only if p is ≥1 and if p=0 then the limit is 0, right?

Comment: if $p=1/2$, then the limit is equal to $1/2$ as $n^0=1$. If $p$ is equal to $0$, then the limit is equal to $0$ as $n^{-1/2}=1/\sqrt{n}$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Also, it goes to $0$ iif $p-1/2<0$.

Comment: please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check symbol if you find it usefull.